# while loop multiple conditions java

Tags: java, while-loop

So essentially, my while loop will evaluate the first two conditions when the length condition is not present; however when I had the length condition, the loop only evaluates that condition. I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
input=keyboard.next();
while (input.charAt(0)!='F'&&input.charAt(0)!='K'&&input.length()>1) { 
    System.out.println("invalid");
    input=keyboard.next();
}
```

If I'm missing something very obvious (which I probably am), I'm sorry for taking up your time, but thanks anyway for taking the time to look at this question.

I just moved my code to a new file, and it's still not working. I don't understand why I'm being downvoted as I'm just asking a question and have yet to get an answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test123444 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

    String input;


    input=keyboard.next();
  while (input.charAt(0)!='F'&&input.charAt(0)!='K'&&input.length()>1) { 
System.out.println("invalid");
input=keyboard.next();
  }
}


}
```

Comment: Your code executes every time length > 1 you're saying? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: @Nambari I assume input is a String he's calling charAt() on.

Comment: no no my code surpasses the loop when the length condition is present and I input a single character value(doesn't matter what value), but when I don't have the length condition, the f and k conditions work.

Comment: My problem is the loop is ignoring the charAt conditions, and I'm not sure why

Comment: Well when you input a single character your code SHOULD "surpass" meaning skip over the loop, because a single character does not have length greater than 1.

Comment: Start by defining what's `keyboard`. I copied and pasted your code in a simple Java console app and defined `Scanner keyboard` and the code worked as expected.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It might not be a Scanner, though.

Comment: @whowantsakookie that's what I'm asking. If its not a `Scanner`, how would we know what's returning `keyboard.next` then?

Comment: I do have a scanner keyboard = new scanner(System.in) in my code earlier with other variables, but I'm unsure

Comment: Edit your question and show more code. Looks like the problem is somewhere else. This code works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kon implies in the comments above, what you need to write is:

```
while (input.charAt(0) != 'F' && input.charAt(0) != 'K' || input.length() > 1) {
```

That is — you want your loop to run if `input` has more than one character *or* if its first character is neither `'F'` nor `'K'`. Your current code will enter the loop only if `input` has more than one character *and* its first character is neither `'F'` nor `'K'`.

Or, better yet:

```
while (! input.equals("F") && ! input.equals("K")) {
```

Comment: apparently I lost 6 ranking by asking this question and following up with comments. If I could upvote your answer I would, thanks

Comment: +1 First answer to actually be helpful.

Comment: @gucci Well if you can't upvote you can still accept his answer

Comment: @gucci: Regarding the downvotes . . . I think people were confused about what you were asking. (It seems that English isn't your native language, and that you're new to Java.) One of the criteria for downvotes is "not clear", which for many people this was. In the future, I suggest that you post a short complete program that demonstrates your problem. In this case, your posted code-snippet depended on code that you didn't post, and it wasn't very clear what you wanted it to do. With a little bit of work, you could have created something clearer that could stand on its own.

Answer (score -1):

In your while loop, you specify the `input.length() > 1` condition. Since you are using `keyboard.next()` to grab your next input, I assume that `input` will only have a length of 1. That's why it works if you remove that test case.

If you want to loop through strings that the user can input into the console via, use `Scanner`. You can use it by making it listen for console input like this: `new Scanner(System.in)`. Use `scanner.next()` to wait for input.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `keyboard` *is* a `Scanner`. You've misunderstood the problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean to do with the scanner.next() (have not used that before)

Comment: my problem is, when all three conditions are in the code, it only evaluates the length condition, not the F or K condition

Comment: -1: If `keyboard` is a `java.util.Scanner` object, then this problem never arise.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP never made that clear, though. I assumed it was a class called `Keyboard` and grabbed the next key that was pushed. "keyboard" seems like sort of an odd name for a `Scanner`.

Comment: If you didn't know that, then you should start posting a comment instead of answer (otherwise I would have posted an answer :] ).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `input.length() > 1` is always `false`, which makes the test condition in your `while` loop false (for `&&`, if one condition is false, then the whole thing is `false`)

Thus, if you leave `input.length()>1` in your condition, no matter whether if `input.charAt(0)!='F'` is `true/false` or `input.charAt(0)!='K'` is `true/false`, the thrid condition will be false and your loop body never executes.

Comment: but when I input a 1 char symbol, it has a length which is true, so shouldn't it repeat the loop?

Comment: 1 > 1 is certainly false...

Comment: even as I have switched the > symbol to the other way around, It still does not work but the thing is I only want a 1 char input, not a 2 char so while my input is greater than 1, I want a new input

Comment: 1 < 1 is also certainly false...

Comment: @gucci As Luiggi mentioned you really need to provide more code, an example of input and what you expect the results to be. As stated there is plenty of ambiguous information.